BTCRecover for finding lost BTC?
So I know BTCRecover has been around but I have some questions about it before I risk using it...

I asked about finding my lost BTC in that I dont know what wallet it was stored in but I have my both seed and also passcode to about a 95+% accuracy but no one suggested BTCRecover?  Is there a reason?

All threads and posts not only here but others for "BTCRecover" seems to be years ago... is there a reason there is not much talk about it in the last couple of months?

If it is legit to use, is this the correct homepage?


https://btcrecover.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

And is this the correct Github?

https://github.com/3rdIteration/btcrecover
Because I also found this but i hear this is outdated?
https://github.com/gurnec/btcrecover

Is this guy the creator of it?

https://www.youtube.com/@CryptoGuide/

If not, is there a great tutorial (preferably video) I can find on using BTCRecover from a legit tech?

I see all these old posts and docs on recovering pass and seed phrases but no talk of finding the right WALLET my BTC lives in... is this still good for that, will it actually tell me the most likely or exact wallet it is in?


TIA

Welcome to bitcoin.stackexchange.com. This Q&A website works best when you ask one question at a time. See example. This helps prevent duplicated answers (and maybe poor or contradictory answers), helps us direct you to existing high-quality answers and helps people in the future with a question similar to one of yours, to find answers to a question you raise.
